# Win8.1 OneDrive is renaming files

Tags: onedrive

In c:\users\userName\OneDrive I have a dir named PowerShell.  All the files in the PowerShell dir are available offline.
In c:\users\userName\OneDrive\PowerShell I have a file:  `glargle.ps1`.
OneDrive keeps renaming it to `glargle-computerName.ps1`.

Why is it doing that, and how do I make it *not* rename my darn files?

Answer (score 1):

It means that the file was simultaneously changed on multiple computers, and there was a synchronisation conflict.